# 'ReflectionException' Class translator does not exists

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, localization

I'm trying to use localization as follow,

```
$types = trans('constants.type');
```

I have created `constants.php` file as follows (which is in config directory) and this are it's language files,

```
/resources
    /lang
        /en
            constants.php
        /es
            constants.php
```

## constants.php

```
return ['type' => 'Type'];
```

same way it translated in other file with same format, but this things gives me following error

***Note:*** I have used this in config directory's file,

> (1/1) ReflectionException
>   Class translator does not exist
>
> in Container.php (line 729)
>   at ReflectionClass->__construct('translator')
>   in Container.php (line 729)
>   at Container->build('translator')
>   in Container.php (line 608)
>   at Container->resolve('translator')
>   in Container.php (line 575)
>   at Container->make('translator')

## Problem:

[`trans()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-trans) method not working in `constants.php` file which i have created in `config` directory as follow,

/config
    constants.php

Comment: Did you modify config/app.php providers array at all?

Comment: Nope i haven't modify it at all

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can't use `trans()` in any config files, because they are loaded before the translation service is registered (which is why you are getting `Class translator does not exist`).

Answer (score 0):

If the other answer did not work it means:

You most probably **deleted**

`Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,` in your `config/app.php` file.